# Failed to add foreign key constraints. Missing index for constraints

Tags: mysql, sql

I keep getting this error on SQL - I've checked the answers, but as far as I can see the datatypes are the exact same? Not sure if I'm missing something.

```
Create table books (
    ISBN BIGINT(13) UNSIGNED,
    Title varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    Author varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    Publishing_Year int,
    Publisher varchar(100),
    Genre varchar(20),
    Copies int
);

CREATE TABLE loans (
    loan_id BIGINT(10) UNSIGNED,
    user_id INT(5) UNSIGNED,
    card_id INT(8) UNSIGNED,
    ISBN BIGINT(13) UNSIGNED,
    loan_date DATE,
    return_by DATE,
    Primary key (loan_id),
    Foreign key (user_id) references users (user_id),
    Foreign key (card_id) references library_cards (card_id),
    Foreign key (ISBN) references books (ISBN)
);
```

Comment: Have you created the `users` and `library_cards` tables already?

Comment: Also, books should have primary key ISBN

Comment: @Jayvee I can't believe I completely missed this - feel so stupid! Thank you, this was the issue!

Comment: @Anna . . . I would suggest that you delete the question.